# challenging string algorithm on pattern matching from bioinformatics

Tags: algorithm

I was told by a friend the following challenge problem.

Given `{A, T, G, C}` as our alphabet, we want to know *the number of valid phrases* with a specified length `n` with the following recursive pattern definition:

- `pat=pat1pat2`, i.e. concatenate two patterns together to form a new pattern `pat`.
- `pat=(pat1|pat2)`, i.e. choosing either one of the patterns `pat1` or `pat2` to form a new pattern `pat`.
- `pat=(pat1*)`, i.e. repeating pattern `pat1` any number of times (can be 0) to form a new pattern `pat`.

A phrase formed from the alphabet set `{A, T, G, C}` is said to satisfy a pattern if it can be formed by above pattern definition; its length is the number of alphabets.

A few examples:

- Given a pattern `((A|T|G)*)` and `n=2`, the number of valid phrases
  is 9, since there are `AA`, `AT`, `AG`, `TA`, `TT`, `TG`, `GA`, `GT`,
  `GG`.
- Given a pattern `(((A|T)*)|((G|C)*))` and `n=2`, the number of valid phrases
  is 8, since there are `AA`, `AT`, `TA`, `TT`, `GG`, `GC`, `CG`, `CC`.
- Given a pattern `((A*)C(G*))` and `n=3`, the number of valid phrases
  is 3, since there are `AAC`, `ACG`, `CGG`.

Please point to me the source of this problem if you have ever seen it and your ideas to tackle it.

Comment: This is equivalent to the problem of determining the number of **words** of the given length `n` in the **regular language** `L` defined by your "pattern". These are the standard terms for CS, and there is plenty of literature available with these terms. You'll probably have better luck getting answers on the cstheory SE site.

Comment: CS theory would close this question as off-topic.

Comment: @KyleJones: Thanks for the hint, was not aware of CS theory's "research-level" restriction. Their FAQ says Math SE would be the right place.

Comment: Try the following: http://www.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~mackerma/ThreeNewAlgorithmsForRegularLanEnum.pdf — it's not exactly what you want, but it explains how to *enumerate* the words. You can count words this way as well, but I doubt it's the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of letters A,C,G, and T makes me think of DNA base pair sequences.  But as thiton wrote, clearly this problem was lifted from the study of regular languages.  Google "regular language enumeration" and you should find plenty of research papers and code to get you started.  I'd be surprised if computing the number of matching strings for these patterns were not a #P-complete problem, so expect run-times exponential in n.